# json schema, conditional dependency by property being present or not

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I have this schema requirement where if A and B are not present C has to be and if C is present A and B should not be.

*For example:*

```
{
  "group1": {
    "a": 10
  },
  "group2": {
    "group3": {
      "b": 30
    }
  },
  "group4": {
    "c": 20
  }
}
```

If `a` is present, `b` and `c` should not be in the json. 
If `b` and `c` are present, `a` should not be in the json.

I can see that in the v6 json schema spec there is something keyword `switch` that could help with this requirements but not being able to make it work.

Is this schema validation even possible with the current specs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

draft-06 is the current spec, but there is no conditional yet.
draft-07 has if/then/else using which you can:

```
{
  "if": {"required": ["a"]},
  "then": {"not": {"$ref": "#/definitions/bc"}},
  "else": {"$ref": "#/definitions/bc"},
  "definitions": {
    "bc": {
      "anyOf": [
        {"required": ["b"]},
        {"required": ["c"]}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Currently if/then/else is supported in [Ajv](https://github.com/epoberezkin/ajv) with ajv-keywords.

Any conditional can be expressed without if/then/else using keywords anyOf, allOf and not:

```
{
  "anyOf": [
    {"allOf": [ifSchema, thenSchema]},
    {"allOf": [{"not": ifSchema}, elseSchema]}
  ]
}
```

Comment: thanks! how would it work in my example with the second option?

Comment: Just substitute the subschemas from the first sample